# TestNG test results getting 0

Tags: testng

After run the selenium rc with testNG getting results like this

```
  [TestNG] Running:
  /tmp/testng-eclipse--383064893/testng-customsuite.xml
===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

test suite results

```
===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0  
===============================================
```

out put commands

```
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@68e4a47: 16 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@38c8c892: 38 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@1abe675c: 0 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@741bb804: 13 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@665d7a8d: 5 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 0 ms
```

Comment: Please post your testng suite here, or otherwise explain how you're kicking off the tests

Answer (score 0):

Testng not finds classes with test. Start from working examples, for example from : http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/testng-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a testng.xml, don't forget to point your project to that xml file, because if you don't then the TestNG will create an xml programatically.

Details in the answer: [How to make TestNG to add parameters to testng-customsuite.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262246/how-to-make-testng-to-add-parameters-to-testng-customsuite-xml)