# How to make TestNG to add parameters to testng-customsuite.xml?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

In eclipse, when we run some java file, having test methods, by right clicking on it and selecting **Run As -> TestNG Test**, we can see following line in 'Console' tab -

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1663319006\testng-customsuite.xml
```

This means TestNG generates `testng-cutomsuite.xml` and runs it.

**testng-cutomsuite.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default suite">
  <test verbose="2" name="Default test">
    <classes>
      <class name="org.test.saifur.StackOverflowTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Default test -->
</suite> <!-- Default suite -->
```

But if I've `testng.xml` in my project and it has parameters like -

```
<parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
<parameter name="baseUrl" value="http://stackoverflow.com" />
```

and when I run my test class as TestNG through eclipse, I want these parameters to be added to `testng-customsuite.xml` so that those parameters will be used in the test script.

Is there any way by which I can achieve above?

Comment: How are those parameters decided? Can't you use a `@DataProvider` instead?

Comment: I would have provided them like that, but in my automation framework, I'm initializing Selenium WebDriver(driver) to open browser and baseUrl to open application url in one file. Rather than doing it in every test file.

Answer (score 3):

I got answer for this question from testng-users google groups(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/q7mLtIsEUCc). Posting same here so that if others who are looking for this get benefited -

`Set your testng.xml as a TestNG template xml file via Project > Properties > TestNG in eclipse. What you are looking for should now be available.
This feature exists only in eclipse and not in IntelliJ`

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/8zsa6X0TnnQ) , this is one  another link, so thought of sharing for someone looking for answer. It shows exactly what your question ask. We need to create  XML Template globally and then

`c.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("n")` this can get the parameters in `@Test`